# Android, использование иконок и изображений с лицензией CCA

Tags: android, изображения

Хочу использовать в приложении изображения, например, с https://www.iconfinder.com/. Многие лицензии требуют размещения ссылки на автора. Каким образом принято размещать ссылки на авторов изображений в программах для Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правило, в разделе "Настройки - О программе"